# How to write mysql query to insert values only if foreign_key exists

Tags: mysql, sql, liquibase

I am having a `user_role` table which has `user_id` referred as a foreign_key from `user` table.

```
desc user;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| e_key            | varchar(256) | NO  | UNI   | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

desc user_role;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name            | varchar(256) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id            | int(11) | NO  |     | UNIQ    |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to create a test data to insert values into `user_role` table only if the user_id exists. User can be identified by the unique key 'e_key'. I am searching for some query like this

```
SET @user_id = (select u.id from user u where u.e_key = 'dave');
IF(@user_id IS NOT NULL) THEN
BEGIN
INSERT INTO user_role(`name`, user_id) VALUES ('admin', @user_id) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = 'admin';
END;
END IF;
```

But the sql throws an error. Is there any way to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: What error does it throw? Show it in quote blocks.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could change the INSERT to use a SELECT as the source of the field to insert, with the SELECT checking the user table.

Something like this:-

```
INSERT INTO user_role(`name`, user_id) 
SELECT 'admin', id 
FROM user 
WHERE id = @user_id 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `name` = 'admin';
```

Answer (score 0):

If in your work scenario you always first add user, and only later user role - consider changing the foreign key order.

It seems that in that case it is better to have user_role table to reference the user table, and not vice versa.